# Missing js & css after install extension in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, mailchimp

Everything was fine before install a marketplace extension.
I installed with the following code:

```
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2
```

and then I check the frontpage, some of the JS and CSS file are unable to load. (at this moment I didn't do setup:upgrade & deploy)

The error message is as follow:

```
(index):665 GET https://kuohua.ca/online-store/pub/static/version1539890455/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_CA/icon-fonts/font/porto-icons.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 403
GET https://kuohua.ca/online-store/pub/static/version1539890455/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_CA/images/select-bg.svg 500
(index):840 
GET https://kuohua.ca/online-store/pub/static/version1539890455/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_CA/icon-fonts/font/porto-icons.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 500
GET https://kuohua.ca/online-store/pub/static/version1539890455/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_CA/js/jquery.stellar.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
Uncaught Error: Script error for: js/jquery.stellar.min
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (24ff3db778301e9fe22234bb3893e837.min.js:16)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (24ff3db778301e9fe22234bb3893e837.min.js:112)
GET https://kuohua.ca/online-store/pub/static/version1539890455/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_CA/Mageplaza_Core/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

Anyone knows what happened? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

After installing new module, you should always run these commands, otherwise it would never work properly.

> php bin/magento module:enable --all
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy

Comment: actually I didn't install any module, I just download one

Comment: yes you did - "composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2"